# Evaluate the integral: $\int e^{-θ}\cos3θdθ$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral: $$\int e^{-θ}\cos3θdθ$$

My attempt:

$$I = \int e^{-θ}\cos3θdθ$$
$$u = \cos3θ \implies du = -3\sin3θdθ$$
$$dv = e^{-θ} \implies v = -e^{-θ}$$

$$(*)\int udv = uv - \int vdu $$ 
$$I =(cos3θ)(-e^{-θ}) - 3\int (e^{-θ})\sin3θdθ$$
$$u = \sin3θ\implies du = 3cos3θdθ$$
$$dv = e^{-θ} \implies v = -e^{-θ}$$
$$I = (\cos3θ)(-e^{-θ})-3((\sin3θ)(-e^{-θ}) + 3\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ) + C$$
$$I = -\cos3θe^{-θ}+3\sin3θe^{-θ} - 9\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ + C$$
$$9\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ = -\cos3θe^{-θ}+3\sin3θe^{-θ} + C$$
$$\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ = \frac{e^{-θ}(-\cos3θ+3\sin3θ)}9 + C$$
$$∴ \int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ = \frac{e^{-θ}(3\sin3θ-\cos3θ)}9 + C$$

However the solution in the back of the book doesn't match my answer, and I have no idea where I messed up.

Comment: You have $I = xyz - 9I + C$, and you transformed it into $9I = xyz+C$. You simply forgot that you already had $1\cdot I$ on the left.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

An easy method is:
$$\int e^{-\theta}\cos3\theta d\theta=\mathrm{Re}\int e^{-\theta+3i\theta} d\theta$$

Answer (score 4):

You need to add $9\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ $ to the each side of the equation, so your left hand side becomes  $$\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ + 9\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ  = 10\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ $$

This gives you, then,  $$\int (e^{-θ})\cos3θdθ = \frac {(3\sin3θ-\cos3θ)}{10 e^\theta} + C$$

Comment: Oh wow, I never noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!! Otherwise, all looks good!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice when you know you helped +1

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for the support, @Amzoti!